# Avoid single point of failure for Bloomberg API client

Tags: bloomberg

I have an API client (written in Java) subscribing market data by Bloomberg API and it saves data to database. But any program may goes down due to some reasons.

To avoid single point of failure, I am thinking to have multiple API clients running at the same time. But there is no unique identifier inside the event, so how can I avoid duplicate data inside the database? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For TRADE events you can leverage some trade identifier field. For Quote ticks you will need to reconcile using multiple fields like quote value, timestamp with higher time solution, still no guarantee for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Subscribe to BAR data. Then there is a unique identifier of market data: the time and the security. Downside: lower resolution (per minute at best, vs individual ticks)

Option 2: do a best effort when subscribing, then do a historical request and replace the data you got when subscribing with the historical response. When making a historical request you know when you have completed processing the response successfully. It's up to you when to do the historical request to replace the data from the subscription. Could be every few minutes or end of day.